# Xcode profiling instrument call tree does not recognize my source code

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks

I'm using Xcode's Memory Leak profiling instrument:
[image]
Green boxes are my app's name in lowercase.

I'm trying to figure out why the call tree shows the "framework" icon next to calls in my app's code instead of that black profile icon like normal. This is preventing me from finding my source code that's causing a memory leak.

I tried using the File > Symbols... menu and saw this:
[image]

I located the .app.dSYM file from the Xcode organizer and copied it to outside the .xcarchive file where I could select it from the above "locate" button. THEN I GET THIS:
[image]

Anyone have an idea what's going on?

Comment: It seems odd that the "Binary Path:" is in red. Isn't that an indication that Xcode can't find that file?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I just don't know why that happened or what would fix it.

Comment: Ah, ok I'm just an idiot. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Alright, I just needed to point Instruments to the binary instead of the dSYM file. 
Click the folder button next to the red text, then navigate to /Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/-/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/

Thanks to @user1118321 for pointing out the thing I missed (obvious red text). A symbolication failure usually suggests the dSYM is missing, but you also need the binary.

Comment: Thanks a lot for publishing answer! By the way, does anybody know way to add binaries for all Swift-modules (defined by pods) at once?